# Is crop rotation actually necessary?

Tags: banished

Is crop rotation necessary?  I don't see any adverse effects from not rotating crops.  I started this game on Easy.  Is this feature not added into the game, or is it only necessary on harder settings?

Comment: Where have you heard that you have to rotate your crops?

Comment: Some of the game guides say you need to do it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As of 7/3/2014 according to the banished wiki:

http://banished-wiki.com/wiki/Farming

*"Farming can be considered a sustainable method of obtaining food for your citizens, though farming for many seasons in one place will ruin the soil.[1] Though, the developer has confirmed that soil degradation has not been implemented."*

In other words, no, at the moment it is not necessary